# Object.defineProperty called on non-object error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this error in jQuery about this code .. and i can't fix it .. i don't understand it and the console log ...
Code is a notifications tool in Blogger that runs cookies

> Object.defineProperty called on non-object .... at Function.defineProperty ()

```
$(function() {
  var view = settingsnoti["noti-bloghomepageUrl"];
  var message = void 0 !== settingsnoti["word"] ? settingsnoti["word"] : "";
  var _0x322dc6 = false !== settingsnoti["allow-noti"];
  var a_second = void 0 !== settingsnoti.expires ? settingsnoti.expires : 7;
  var _0x48e20c = void 0 !== settingsnoti["color"] ? settingsnoti["color"] : "#388d80";
  var styleFloat = void 0 !== settingsnoti.float ? settingsnoti.float : "right";
  var lessFileName = false !== settingsnoti["ltr"];
  language_form = "" !== message ? message : ["تحديد الكل كمقروء", "قبول", "إلغاء", "عرض", "زيارة", "إشعار", "إعلان", "تحديث", "راجع مالجديد!!"];
  var load = function(_height) {
    return language_form[parseInt(_height - 1)];
  };
  switch (lessFileName) {
    case true:
      badge_dir = "ltr-badge";
      break;
    case false:
    default:
      badge_dir = "rtl-badge";
  }! function($) {
    var abbr;
    var i = "#notification-badge";
    var element = 'input[name="badge[]"]';
    var value = "#notibadgeBtn";
    $.fn.ihavebadge = function(name, all) {
      var map_el = $(this);
      var item = $.extend({
        "childTypes": settingsnoti,
        "delay": 1,
        "expires": a_second,
        "onAccept": function() {},
        "ImageSize": 116,
        "substring": 140,
        "float": styleFloat,
        "ltr": lessFileName,
        "bloggcodeNAM": "PicFast",
        "bloggcodeURI": "https://blogg-code.blogspot.com",
        "macrosid": "AKfycbykx1ZVe0t0qmw4sZ2Pez4iYNFXnv8w6HAANNtXs5VCX38RS_A",
        "noImage": "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7CnHTs2OKS8/Wo214lKp0KI/AAAAAAAACPk/CD1mAZz7IwI32hkGM3aVbD6Tefw78IkvgCLcBGAs/s72/no-img-300x300-blogg-code.jpg",
        "Imgavatar": "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mP-2bvOaWuM/XAkrMTFABaI/AAAAAAAADjU/tqSHDVesLcYwQ1rXt1MVvG3TENbJqMvcQCLcBGAs/s72/no-user.png",
        "Monthformat": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
      }, name);
      var types = {
        "getstyle": function(p) {
          $(p).appendTo($("head"));
        },
        "b": function(context, data, res, a, f, cb) {
          context.prop("checked", cb);
          context.attr("data-auto", data).parent().css({
            "background-color": res,
            "opacity": a,
            "pointer-events": f
          });
        },
        "getlocation": function(index) {
          if (index) {
            setInterval(function() {
              window.location.href = index;
            }, 2E3);
          }
        },
        "getcopyright": function(delete_behavior_form) {

          var artistTrack = '<li class="notirights px ads badg_radius5 styleimpo"><label class="notirights">' + load(7) + ':</label><span class="notirights type">' + item.bloggcodeNAM + '</span><span class="notirights ilink"><a class="notirights badgehover-opa badg_radius30" href="' + item.bloggcodeURI + '" target="_blank">' + load(5) + "</a></span></li>";
          if (0 !== $(".notirights").length) {
            $(".notirights").each(function() {
              if (($(this).css("opacity") < 1 || "hidden" == $(this).css("visibility") || $(this).is(":hidden")) && $(i).is(":visible")) {
                types.getlocation(item.bloggcodeURI);
              }
            });
          } else {
            $(delete_behavior_form).prepend(artistTrack);
          }
        }
      };
      types.getstyle("<style type='text/css'>div#notification-badge .button,div#notification-badge ul li label,#notification-badge input[type=checkbox],div#notification-badge .badgehover-var:hover {color:" + _0x48e20c + ";}div#notification-badge .button.done,#notification-badge input[type=checkbox]:checked::before,div#notification-badge .ilink a {background-color:" + _0x48e20c + ";}div#notification-badge .button.done,div#notification-badge .button.cancel:hover {border: 1px solid " + _0x48e20c + ";}div#notification-badge .styleimpo {display:block!important;opacity:1!important;visibility:visible!important;width:auto!important;height:auto!important;padding:5px!important;background-color:#ffffff!important;border:1px solid" + _0x48e20c + "!important}</style>");
      var pix_color = "";
      Math.floor(+Math["random"]() + 1);
      if ($("body").hasClass("Preview")) {
        var retryLinkHref = view.replace(/\/$/, "");
      } else {
        retryLinkHref = window.location.origin;
      }
      var requestOrUrl = retryLinkHref.toLowerCase() + "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&orderby=updated&start-index=1&max-results=1";
      $.ajax({
        "url": requestOrUrl,
        "dataType": "jsonp",
        "type": "GET",
        "success": function(xhr, status, custom) {
          if ("entry" in xhr.feed) {

            var i = 0;
            for (; i < xhr.feed.entry.length; i++) {
              var data = xhr.feed.entry[i];

              var version = 0;
              for (; version < data.link.length; version++) {
                var result = data.link[version];
                if ("replies" == (result = data.link[version]).rel && "text/html" == result.type) {
                  result.title;
                  result.href;
                }
                if ("alternate" == result.rel) {
                  var replacements = result.href;
                  if (-1 !== replacements.indexOf(".blogspot.")) {
                    replacements = replacements.replace("http://", "https://");
                  }
                  break;
                }
              }
              var word = item.Monthformat;
              var nickname = data.updated.$t;
              var _0x4afe5a = nickname.substring(0, 10);
              var contentId = _0x4afe5a.substring(0, 4);
              var cPointX = _0x4afe5a.substring(5, 7);
              var linkCssId = _0x4afe5a.substring(8, 10) + "-" + word[parseInt(cPointX - 1)] + "-" + contentId;
              var _0x417c4f = (data.published.$t.substr(0, 10).replace(/\-/g, "_"), data.title.$t);
              var height = item.Imgavatar;

              if (void 0 !== data.author[0].uri) {
                var value = data.author[0].name.$t;
                if (data.author[0].gd$image.src.match("blogblog")) {
                  var whatToScale = height;
                } else {
                  whatToScale = data.author[0].gd$image.src;
                }
                var heightInCells = whatToScale.replace(/http:\/\//, "https://").replace("/72-c/", "/s220/");
                var id = data.author[0].uri.$t;
              } else {
                value = "Unknown";
                heightInCells = height;
                id = "javascript:void(0)";
              }
              if (void 0 !== data.media$thumbnail) {
                var entryOrArray = data.media$thumbnail.url;
                var id = item.ImageSize;
                var timestamp = entryOrArray.replace(/http:\/\//, "https://").replace("/s72-c/", "/s" + id + "/").replace("?imgmax=800", "");
              } else {
                if (void 0 !== data.content && null != data.content.$t.match(/youtube\.com.*(\?v=|\/embed\/)(.{11})/)) {
                  var shapePathsCollection = data.content.$t.match(/youtube\.com.*(\?v=|\/embed\/)(.{11})/).pop();
                  if (11 == shapePathsCollection.length) {
                    timestamp = "//img.youtube.com/vi/" + shapePathsCollection + "/0.jpg";
                  }
                } else {
                  if (void 0 !== data.content && null != data.content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/)) {
                    timestamp = data.content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/)[1];
                  } else {
                    timestamp = item.noImage;
                  }
                }
              }
              if (void 0 !== data.summary) {
                var matches = data.summary.$t.replace(/<\S[^>]*>/g, "");
                var resizewidth = matches.substring(0, item.substring) + "...";
                if (300 < matches.length) {
                  matches.substring(0, 170);
                }
                if (100 < matches.length) {
                  matches.substring(0, 100);
                }
              } else {
                if (void 0 !== data.content) {
                  var result = data.content.$t.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
                  resizewidth = result.substring(0, item.substring) + "...";
                  if (300 < result.length) {
                    result.substring(0, 170);
                  }
                  if (100 < result.length) {
                    result.substring(0, 100);
                  }
                } else {
                  resizewidth = "";
                }
              }
              var _0xb2707 = data.id.$t.split(".post-").pop();
              pix_color = pix_color + ('<li class="px badg_radius5"><input type="checkbox" id="badge-id-cookietypeupdated-' + _0xb2707 + '" name="badge[]" value="updated-' + _0xb2707 + '" data-auto="off"/><label for="badge-id-cookietypeupdated-' + _0xb2707 + '">' + load(8) + ':</label>' + load(9) + '<abbr class="timeago idate badg_radius30" title="' + nickname + '">' + linkCssId + '</abbr><span class="icontent"><a class="badgehover-var" href="' + replacements + '" target="_blank"><img class="badg_radius5" src="' + timestamp + '"/>' + _0x417c4f + '</a></span><span class="inameauthor"><a class="badgehover-var" href="' + id + '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img class="badg_radius100" src="' + heightInCells + '"/><i class="authorname">' + value + '</i></a></span></li>');
            }
          }
          var isScaytNode = clone("badgeControl");
          var workspace = clone("badgeControlPrefs");
          if (isScaytNode && workspace && "reinit" != all) {
            var item2 = true;
            if (false == isScaytNode) {
              item2 = false;
            }
            filter(item2, item.expires, i);
          } else {
            $(i).remove();
            var summaryHtml = "";
            preferences = JSON.parse(workspace);
            $.each(item.childTypes, function(canCreateDiscussions, url) {
              if ("" !== url.type && "" !== url.value && "" !== url.link && url.type) {
                var th_field = "";
                if (false !== url.link) {
                  th_field = '<span class="ilink"><a class="badgehover-opa badg_radius30" href="' + url.link + '" target="_blank">' + load(4) + '</a></span>';
                }
                summaryHtml = summaryHtml + ('<li class="px badg_radius5"><input type="checkbox" id="badge-id-cookietype' + url.value + '" name="badge[]" value="' + url.value + '" data-auto="off"/><label for="badge-id-cookietype' + url.value + '">' + load(6) + ':</label><span class="type">' + url.type + '</span>' + th_field + '</li>');
              }
            });
            var artistTrack = '<div id="notification-badge" class="' + badge_dir + 'badg_shadowkit badg_radius2" style="display: none;"><div id="badge-types"><p><button class="button btn-top select" id="badge-btn-select" type="button">' + load(1) + '</button></p><ul>' + summaryHtml + pix_color + '</ul></div><p><button class="button btn-bottom done badgehover-opa badg_radius5" id="badge-btn-done" type="button">' + load(2) + '</button><button class="button btn-bottom cancel badg_radius5" id="badge-btn-cancel" type="button">' + load(3) + '</button></p></div>';
            $(map_el).append(artistTrack);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $.each(preferences, function(canCreateDiscussions, domRootID) {
                if (1 != $('#badge-id-cookietype' + domRootID).length) {
                  abbr = $('#badge-id-cookietype' + domRootID).length;
                }
              });
              var d = preferences.length;
              var v = $(element).length;
              var m = v - d;
              if (0 == abbr && (m = v - d + 1), d || (m = v), 10 < m && (m = "+9"), 0 < m) {
                var artistTrack = '<span class="' + badge_dir + 'badge alert badg_radius100">' + m + '</span>';
                $(value).append(artistTrack).addClass("Animat-notifications");
              }
            }, item.delay);
            $(window).scroll(function() {
              fn(i, value);
            });
            $("body").on("click", value, function() {
              if ($(i).is(":hidden")) {
                $(i).hide(function() {
                  $(".badge").remove();
                  $(value).addClass("active").removeClass("Animat-notifications");
                  var x;
                  var orig_top = $(value).offset().top + $(value).height();
                  if ("left" === item.float) {
                    x = $(value).offset().left;
                    $(this).css({
                      "top": orig_top + "px",
                      "left": x + "px"
                    });
                  } else {
                    if ("right" === item.float) {
                      x = $(window).width() - ($(value).offset().left + $(value).outerWidth());
                      $(this).css({
                        "top": orig_top + "px",
                        "right": x + "px"
                      });
                    }
                  }
                  $.each(preferences, function(canCreateDiscussions, conid) {
                    if ($.fn.ihavebadge.preference(conid)) {
                      types.b($("#badge-id-cookietype" + conid), "on", "white", ".4", "none", true);
                    }
                  });
                }).fadeIn(100);
              }
              types.getcopyright("#notification-badge ul");
            });
            $(i).click(function(canCreateDiscussions) {
              if ("BUTTON" !== canCreateDiscussions.target.nodeName) {
                canCreateDiscussions.stopPropagation();
              }
            });
            $(element).on("change", function() {
              if (this.checked) {
                types.b($(this), "on", "white", ".4", "auto");
              } else {
                types.b($(this), "off", "#f8f8f8", "1", "auto");
              }
            });
            $("body").on("click", "#badge-btn-select", function() {
              types.b($(element), "on", "white", ".4", "auto", true);
              $("#badge-btn-done").trigger("click");
            });
            $("body").on("click", "#badge-btn-cancel", function() {
              fn(i, value);
            });
            $("body").on("click", "#badge-btn-advanced", function() {
              types.b($(element), "off", "#f1f1f1", "1", "auto", false);
            });
            $("body").on("click", "#badge-btn-done", function() {
              filter(true, item.expires, i);
              var data = [];
              $.each($(element).serializeArray(), function(canCreateDiscussions, nodes) {
                data.push(nodes.value);
                var item = '#badge-id-cookietype' + nodes.value;
                types.b($(item), "on", "white", ".4", "none");
              });
              trigger("badgeControlPrefs", JSON.stringify(data), 365);
              item.onAccept.call(this);
            });
          }
        }
      });
    };
    $.fn.ihavebadge.cookie = function() {
      var message = clone("badgeControlPrefs");
      return JSON.parse(message);
    };
    $.fn.ihavebadge.preference = function(_relatedTarget) {
      var currentLineStylesCloned = clone("badgeControl");
      var data = clone("badgeControlPrefs");
      return data = JSON.parse(data), false !== currentLineStylesCloned && (false !== data && -1 !== data.indexOf(_relatedTarget));
    };
    var filter = function(key, val, enhanced) {
      trigger("badgeControl", key, val);
      $(enhanced).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        fn(this, value);
      });
    };
    var fn = function(id, el) {
      $(id).removeAttr("style");
      $(el).removeClass("active");
    };
    var trigger = function(y, x, keys) {
      var expected_date2 = new Date;
      expected_date2.setTime(expected_date2.getTime() + 24 * keys * 60 * 60 * 1E3);
      var _0x491ad2 = "expires=" + expected_date2.toUTCString();
      return document.cookie = y + "=" + x + ";" + _0x491ad2 + ";path=/", clone(y);
    };
    var clone = function(method) {
      var data = method + "=";
      var PL$13 = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split(";");
      var PL$17 = 0;
      for (; PL$17 < PL$13.length; PL$17++) {
        var PL$6 = PL$13[PL$17];
        for (;
          " " == PL$6.charAt(0);) {
          PL$6 = PL$6.substring(1);
        }
        if (0 === PL$6.indexOf(data)) {
          return PL$6.substring(data.length, PL$6.length);
        }
      }
      return false;
    };
  }(jQuery);
  var am_Overlay = {
    "onAccept": function() {
      console.log("%cnotification saved...", "color:tomato");
    }
  };
  if (true == _0x322dc6) {
    $("body").ihavebadge(am_Overlay, "reinit");
  } else {
    $("#notibadgeBtn").remove();
  }
});
```

how i can fixed it i want to help please .. and thanks you for all :)

Comment: There's no call to `defineProperty()` anywhere in the code you posted. It's probably happening somewhere in jQuery, but you need to show the stack trace so we know which of your calls is causing it.

Comment: You've also posted hundreds of lines of code. You need to narrow it down to the part with the problem.

Comment: `var am_Overlay = {
"onAccept" : function() {
console.log("%cnotification saved...", "color:tomato");
}
};
if (true == allow_notii) {
$("body").ihavebadge(am_Overlay, "reinit");
} else {
$("#notibadgeBtn").remove();
}`

Comment: When I delete this part of the code the problem will disappear but the add-on will not work

Comment: Sounds like the error is happening in the call to `$("body").ihavebadge()`. Where in that function is it failing? The JavaScript debugger in the browser should show you the stack trace.

Comment: If you're trying to write your own jQuery plugin, you need to be familiar with JS debugging.